# pgloder pg_bulkloader copy postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, copy

HI I'm an Oracle DBA and we are migrating some Oracle DBs to PostgreSQL

We have some csv Files and are loading them to Oracle table with sqlldr which features are "huge"

I know on the PostgreSQL site there is the copy tool or some 3rd party tools
like pgloader but I don't think they are able todo the same as we have done with sqlldr

with copy tool I get errors that some data is missing (but the fiels can be empty)

and with the pgloader I still have some installation issues
but what I read it has not all the features we need

are there any other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a sed/awk/perl sort of approach to filtering your input before sending it to `copy`. `copy` itself has a fair number of configuration options; perhaps not as broad as `sqlldr`, but fairly flexible none the less.

Comment: "*to do the same as we have done with sqlldr*" - and what exactly is that? What are the features you are missing?

Comment: 1. error logging with copy - as far as we see there is no such feature like bad records - 2. fill with default values 3. case statements direct in copy